# Create and Call External JS files

Tags: javascript

I've spent a great deal of time creating and testing an application with quite a few functions. Now that I have configured everything and it works how I want, I would like to begin cleaning up the code so its not 400 lines of mush.

I have already created an external CSS file and would like to do something similar for the JS and possibly even the HTML (approx 100 lines of code of just HTML, ick).

Admittedly I am a novice programmer but I've picked up quite a bit of knowledge in the short time I've been doing this. What is the best way to separate out the functions into external files and then call them so that the whole application works as it does now?

For example (this is a web mapping application): I have functions for search, basemap gallery,  legend, layers, init, infowindows, etc. Since the code is already written and I'll be creating multiple applications in the future, the goal would be to just have these js functions in files ready to be referenced by whatever application needs them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link an external javascript file, place a script tag with a src attribute pointing to your file.

```
<script src="legend.js"></script>
<script src="layers.js"></script>
<script src="init.js"></script>
```

Calling a function requires nothing special.

```
onclick="myFunction();"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just put all of those functions in one .js file and then call the file from within your web page?

```
<script src="../scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

And then call on your functions as and when you need them?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you might consider doing do is to create a non-global "namespace" for your functions in a fashion such as the following:

```
window.MyApp = window.MyApp || {};
```

The above line can be at the top of *every* file; the first time it is invoked it creates a new namespace/object, subsequently it returns the one you previously created.

Then you can move your functions under MyApp in a manner such as the following:

```
MyApp.func1 = function() {...}
```

Google for creating Javascript namespaces, and possibly also the Javascript module pattern