# Can we configure iis service to process the .js file and return the result

Tags: javascript, iis-7

Added a simple html code under which javascript is included. When I save the code in a file with .html extension then it is processing the file and returning the results. But I want to save the file with extension .js. In this cases it displaying the contents of the file, instead of executing the logic. Is there a option to configure iis so that it interprets .js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split(",");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    // If first entry with this name
    if (pair[0] === "SUB-ID") {
        document.write ("Subscriber ID ::" + pair[1])
        document.write("<br>"); 
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (pair[0] === "MAC") {
        document.write ("MAC Address::" + pair[1])
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
} ();

document.write (query_string[SUB-ID]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are ways to execute Javascript (ClearScript, V8, Chakra) but if you are accessing Window and Document then you need a Window and a Document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create and Call External JS files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710910/create-and-call-external-js-files)

Comment: you can't rename your html file to js, you must create a js file with only the javascript code and do like question above.